# Detecting when multiple downloads are completed

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog, android-broadcast, android-download-manager

I am using `DownloadManager` to download multiple files (12 to be exact). I have setup a `BroadcastReciever` and when `ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE` display an `AlertDialog` like this:

```
manager.enqueue(f1);
manager.enqueue(f2);
manager.enqueue(f3);
......

BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    String action = intent.getAction();
        if (DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE.equals(action)) {
            //Display an alertdialog
        }
    }
};

registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter(DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE));
```

However once the downloads complete, the dialog goes into a loop and keeps reappearing until a forcefully exit the app. Does anyone know why this is happening?

I have found that this is happening because it displays the alertdialog for each completed download. How can I make it show just once when all of the downloads are done?

Comment: Does it work correctly if you only send one download request? The problem could be that many requests are being sent.

Comment: Hmm, I removed all the requests except one and now it works properly (showing the dialog only once). Does that mean that it is showing the dialog for each downloaded file? How can I make it show only once when all of the files have downloaded?

Comment: Set an `int` variable to the number of files you're downloading, and decrement it in the `onReceive()` method. When it `==0`, show your dialog.

Comment: @MikeM. Should I decrement the variable inside of the if statement within the onRecieve method?

Comment: Yepper. Even though you might be registering the Receiver for only `ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE`, it's just good practice to it that way. Among other things, it would make it obvious to anyone reading your code exactly what you're doing.